# Turn on the microphone from inside the web view in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, web, view

I am using web view (WKWebView) in ios app - swift 5 And the application was given access to the microphone ... But it does not run on the website inside Web View ...  and I tried the site in a well-functioning Safari app that uses the microphone
What is the solution ..

thes is my code

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        switch AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().recordPermission {
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.granted:
            print("Permission granted")
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.denied:
            print("Pemission denied")
        case AVAudioSessionRecordPermission.undetermined:
            print("Request permission here")
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().requestRecordPermission({ (granted) in
                // Handle granted
            })
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }

         guard let url = URL(string: "https://") else { return }

          wq.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
          wq.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
          wq.navigationDelegate = self
          navigationItem.title = "abt"
          wq.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36"
          wq.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
          wq.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
          wq.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
          wq.load(URLRequest(url: url))
          self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()
          self.activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true

    }
```

and thes is info.plist

```
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
```